# Вылет при открытии активити с темой "Dialog"

Tags: java, android, android-studio, activity, android-dialog

Собственно, так активити прописана в манифесте:

```xml
        <activity android:name="rockbearltd.fants_game_for_company.ChooseLanguage"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
        </activity>
```

Layout:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#000000">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/language"
        android:textSize="23sp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:paddingBottom="30dp"
        android:paddingTop="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/textChooseLang"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="100"
        tools:ignore="UselessLeaf"
        android:paddingBottom="20dp">

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="50"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/rus_lang_but"
            android:src="@drawable/rus_lang"
            android:background="@drawable/nothing"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:onClick="rus"
            tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="50"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/en_lang_but"
            android:src="@drawable/en_lang"
            android:background="@drawable/nothing"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:onClick="en"
            tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded"/>

        </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Java:

```java
import android.app.Application;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.res.Configuration;

import java.util.Locale;

public class Lang extends Application {

    private Locale locale = null;
    SharedPreferences sPref;
    final String SAVED_TEXT = "saved_text";
    String langSet;

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        if (locale != null) {
            newConfig.locale = locale;
            Locale.setDefault(locale);
            getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(newConfig,
                    getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        sPref = getSharedPreferences("LangSet", MODE_PRIVATE);
        langSet = sPref.getString(SAVED_TEXT, "");
        Configuration config = getBaseContext().getResources().getConfiguration();
        if (langSet.equals("en")){String lang = "default";
            if (!"".equals(lang) && !config.locale.getLanguage().equals(lang)) {
            locale = new Locale(lang);
            Locale.setDefault(locale);
            config.locale = locale;
            getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,
                    getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        }}
        if (langSet.equals("ru")){String lang = "ru";
            if (!"".equals(lang) && !config.locale.getLanguage().equals(lang)) {
                locale = new Locale(lang);
                Locale.setDefault(locale);
                config.locale = locale;
                getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,
                        getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
            }}
        if (langSet == null){String lang = "default";
            if (!"".equals(lang) && !config.locale.getLanguage().equals(lang)) {
                locale = new Locale(lang);
                Locale.setDefault(locale);
                config.locale = locale;
                getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,
                        getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
            }}
    }
}
```

Логи вылета:

```
2020-08-10 01:17:27.601 11402-11402/rockbearltd.fants_game_for_company E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: rockbearltd.fants_game_for_company, PID: 11402
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{rockbearltd.fants_game_for_company/rockbearltd.fants_game_for_company.ChooseLanguage}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Only fullscreen opaque activities can request orientation
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2957)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3032)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1696)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6942)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Only fullscreen opaque activities can request orientation
        at android.app.Activity.onCreate(Activity.java:1038)
        at rockbearltd.fants_game_for_company.ChooseLanguage.onCreate(ChooseLanguage.java:25)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7183)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1221)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2910)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3032) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1696) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6942) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
```

Вылетает при тесте на версии Android 8.0.0. На старом смартфоне с более ранней версией андроида (вроде 5-ая) вылетов нет. Ломаю голову уже пару дней, поиздеваясь над гуглом, ответа так и не нашёл.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну собственно ошибка  `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Only fullscreen opaque activities can request orientation` говорит сама за себя.

Вы пытаетесь установить ориентацию Activity тема которой не является полноэкранной. Для таких Activity задавать ориентацию нельзя.

В манифесте уберите  `android:screenOrientation="portrait"`. Это должно решить вашу проблему

Comment: Упс. А я пытался убрать в layout'е убрать `android:orientation="vertical` и всё съезжало, а про манифест не подумал... Спасибо, помогло. Буду в следующий раз внимательнее.